# OTG USB 3.0 not working in Moto G3

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g, usb-on-the-go, motorola-moto-g3

I recently bought a 32 GB capacity USB 3.0 OTG SanDisk pen drive model number  **SDDD2-032G-G46**.

When connected I was able to view the files in the pen drive and even copy some files, however when I copy relatively bigger files the drive gets ejected.

I tested the same pen drive with **Lenovo K3 Note** and the original **Moto X**, in both the devices it worked perfectly fine and fast.

Does this mean my mobile has a problem with handling USB 3.0 devices? Because when connecting the same drive through OTG cable this didn't happen.

Comment: USB OTG is broken on the Moto G 2015 with Marshmallow... Sorry, just have to wait for Moto to fix it.

Comment: @acejavelin you mean the latest update screwed it? can I expect a fix any time soon?

Comment: Moto fixed it in the last few Lollipop updates, but it broke again in Marshmallow 6.0.0 and still isn't fixed. TBH, I have no idea when it will be fixed,  sorry.